# How to print objects in a Jinja2 template starting from a certain point on the page?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I need to print the list of elements of a data frame column on the template starting at a certain point on the page (let's say 200px, 100px).

My current code prints the elements in the data frame (t1) column superimposed on each other.

```
{% for _, row in t1.iterrows() %}
<p STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:100px; LEFT:200px">{{row["col1"]}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

I have tried other options like `position:relative` and `position:sticky` but it doesn't work.

Comment: if the problem is superimposing and you want each p on as a row, maybe display:block ? also  i'm not sure you can use STYLE upper case, try using style just for the sake of the doubt

Comment: display:block is a style option, what do you mean by looping display blocks ?  i would say just by putting it on style it should work

Comment: Tried using lowercase style... no difference. I am new to flask. How do I use display:block in style?

Comment: yes in style, STYLE="display:block;position:absolute; TOP:100px; LEFT:200px">

Comment: did that... same output :/